# Confused about TL-WN725N

Tags: usb, wifi, power, bluetooth

I have a Raspberry Pi 2 with Ubuntu Mate and I use it with:

TL-WN725N

CSL Nano Bluetooth v4.0.

If I use only the wifi, the signal will be more powerful and the connection more stable than when I use it with the bluetooth dongle.
I increased the USB Power in the /boot/config.txt but how is it possible to understand if all the drivers are correctly installed?
Which command can I use?

Answer (score 2):

WiFi is designed to function as a local area network (LAN) whereas bluetooth is desgined for shorter range personal area network (PAN).

Depending on the class of your bluetooth device, this may have a range of 100 (class1), 10m (class2) or 1m (class 3).

Have a look at /var/log/messages to see what kernel messages are generated when you insert the device- 
`tail -f /var/log/messages`